# How to get the "flat" domain name for a user in .NET 3.5+

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, dns, directoryservices

When we log into our Windows machines at work, we use "CORP\username".

Given a user's SID and the domain controller where they logged in, how do I derive that string? I'm using the DirectoryServices APIs added in .NET 3.5, like this:

```
PrincipalContext domaincontroller = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "192.168.30.115");
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(domaincontroller, IdentityType.Sid, "S-1-5-21-293182769-1777760488-2957165303-1798");
```

I've dug around the domaincontroller object and user object, and see lots of stuff like this:

```
user.Name:              john smith
user.DisplayName:       john smith
user.UserPrincipalName: john.smith@corp.mycompany.com
user.SamAccountName:    john.smith
```

**If I dig deep in the private guts of the UserPrinciple object, I find two fields labelled "domainFlatName" and "FlatDomainName" which contain exactly what I want (screen shot below). What do these mean, and how I can get to them via a public interface?**

[image: Object Inspector Screenshot]

Comment: What's the program environment ? Is it Windows Form or Asp.net ?

Comment: Do you know reflection? It allows you to read private/internal fields freely, http://www.techrepublic.com/article/applied-reflection-dynamically-accessing-properties-of-a-class-at-runtime/6099345

Comment: Have you taken a step back and considered *why* this information isn't easily exposed? Microsoft are trying to encourage a move away from the `DOMAIN\User` style of usernames. What are you actually using this information for, and why does it have to be in this form?

Comment: Whether it's deprecated or not, logging in this way is a reality at my work and at several of our clients. I was ready to go with `UserPrincipalName` (e.g. john.smith@corp.mycompany.com), but that was rejected.

Comment: But how people are logging on should have zero to do with how you interact with their account programmatically - what are you actually *using* this value for?

Comment: This value is displayed back to the user in a few places (i.e. "You're logged in as CORP\username"). It needs to reflect what *they* think of as their login, which means matching what they actually used to login. As it turns out `System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name` gives me exactly what I need. The problem that prompted this question was that I passed only the SID to our server and was trying to reconstruct the login from that. I've given up and just pass the name, now. But this question is still of interest. I think Brian Desmond has answered it, for the most part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting this value is unfortunately non-trivial. The attribute you want is `nETBIOSName` which is stored on the `crossRef` object representing the domain in the configuration NC.

Given you know the DN of the domain (e.g. fabrikam.com is DC=fabrikam,DC=com), you can do a search of the configuration naming context for `(&(objectClass=crossRef)(nCName=DC=fabrikam,DC=com))` and grab the `nETBIOSName` off of there.

Answer (score 1):

So there's several questions here.  Brian Desmond already told you that the "domainFlatName/FlatDomainName" members correspond to the domain's NETBIOS name (and that the NETBIOS name doesn't have to match the DNS name).

So how do you get it?  Brian gave you where it is stored in Active Directory.  You can also get it with the [`DsGetDcName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675983%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function with the `DS_RETURN_FLAT_NAME` flag.  There's probably a wrapper for this function in .NET, but I don't know what it is.

But your real question was how to get the "CORP\username" string.  As you found out, this is easily accessible from `System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name`.  You also could have taken the `SecurityIdentifer` object, and called the `Translate` method to the `NTAccount` type and get it from the Value method.  This is most likely wrapping the [`LookupAccountName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379159%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [`DsCrackNames`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675970%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.  Finally, this string can be retrieved from Active Directory using the constructed attribute msDS-PrincipalName.

Answer (score 0):

I tried again using my own network. Closest I could reach was to use SamAccountName property of UserPrincipal.Current

and then used DirectorySearcher 's SearchRoot.Name property which gave me the result like "DC=CORP"

```
   string sFilter = String.Format("(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(sAMAccountName={0}))", u.SamAccountName);
                DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry(adPath);
                DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(de, sFilter, new string[] { "distinguishedName" });
string dcName = ds.SearchRoot.Name;
```

Extracting CORP from DC=CORP and combining it with u.SamAccountName was the best way I could find

It will be interesting to know if there still exist a direct way to get flatdomainname

Comment: Unfortunately there is no technical reason that mandates that the bottom level DNS label (DC=corp here) match the domain's NetBIOS name (CORP). It's very common for them to be divergent.